# Error message during installing caffe command 'make all'

Tags: caffe

I ran

```
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
make all
```

as suggested on the website to complete the installation.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 with CUDA and OpenBlas.

The error messages showed as follows

> CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::curandGetErrorString(curandStatus)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::weight_gpu_gemm(double const*, double const*, double*)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::forward_gpu_bias(double*, double const*)
>           .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::forward_gpu_bias(float*, float const*)
>           .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::cudnn::dataType::one
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::backward_gpu_gemm(float const*, float const*, float*)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::cublasGetErrorString(cublasStatus_t)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::forward_gpu_gemm(double const*, double const*, double*, bool)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::backward_gpu_gemm(double const*, double const*, double*)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::backward_gpu_bias(double*, double const*)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::forward_gpu_gemm(float const*, float const*, float*, bool)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::weight_gpu_gemm(float const*, float const*, float*)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer::backward_gpu_bias(float*, float const*)
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to caffe::cudnn::dataType::one
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin] Error 1

I only modified Makefile.config.
The modified Makefile.config shown as follows

```
USE_CUDNN := 1
CUSTOM_CXX := g++
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
           -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
           -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
           -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
           -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
           -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50
BLAS := OpenBlas
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute
TEST_GPUID := 0
Q ?= @
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `BLAS` settings in `Makefile.config` to

```
BLAS := open
```

Rather than `'OpenBlas'`.

Comment: @ycliu are you sure CUDA and all its relevant drivers are properly installed?